# Cocos2d-iPhone end scene and return to ViewController

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm trying to end my mini-game written in cocos2d after some time and go back to my view controller. I'm using storyboards and only 1 view is a CocosViewController.

I tried so many things but nothing is fully working. Most solutions causes BAD ACCESS error.

The best thing I have so far:

In GameLayer:

```
UIViewController *root = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window].rootViewController;
if ( [root isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]] ) {
     CustomNavigationController *navC = (CustomNavigationController *)root;
    CocosViewController *cocosVC = (CocosViewController *)[navC.viewControllers lastObject];
     [cocosVC performSelector:@selector(gameEnd)];
}
```

In my CocosViewController:

```
- (void)gameEnd
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gameEnd" sender:self];
}
```

gameEnd is a segue to main UIViewController. This moves me to CocosViewController (and not to main UIViewController) and it is not stoping the game.

What is the correct way to stop the game and go back to view controller in cocos2d? I spend 2 days working on this and I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: 1) Why do you call `[cocosVC performSelector:@selector(gameEnd)];` and not simply `[cocosVC gameEnd];`? 2) Can you show the full error stack trace? That should help pinpoint the problem.

Comment: 1) I just found this one working, your solutions seems to work too. 2) It is always only Thread 1: BAD ACCESS (..) and not stack trace. Can you tell me what is a proper way to stop and exit scene? I tried also [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end], [[CCDirector sharedDirector] popScene] and much more. Evrytime I get BAD ACCESS error.